# ES6 angular-meteor ng-table getData function not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ngtable, angular-meteor

I'm trying to refactor my code to ES6. I'm using angular-meteor and ng-table. Before refactoring, the data is shown on the table. However, after refactoring to ES6 syntax, the data doesn't show anymore. This is a snippet of the refactored code:

```
class MyController {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, NgTableParams, MyService) {
        'ngInject';

        $reactive(this).attach($scope);

        this.subscribe('myCollection');

        this.myService = MyService;

        this.helpers({
            items() {
                return this.myService.getItems();
            },
            itemTableParams() {
                const data = this.getReactively('items');

                return new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count: 10
                }, {
                    total: data.length,
                    getData: (params) => {
                        // not called
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyService {
    getItems() {
        return MyCollection.find({}, {
            sort: {
                dateCreated: -1
            }
        });
    }
}

export default angular.module('MyModule', [angularMeteor, ngTable, MyService])
    .component('MyComponent', {
        myTemplate,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: MyController
    })
    .service('MyService', MyService);
```

The `const data` is getting populated but `getData` isn't getting called. The table in the template is using `ctrl.itemTableParams` as the value for `ng-table` attribute and its `ng-repeat` is `item in $data`.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the `getData` function isn't called? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S.
When I try to set `NgTableParams` to a `const tableParams`, and then call the `reload()` function, `getData` is triggered. But the thing is, it's not rendering the data on the table. I set the table as:

```
itemTableParams() {
    const data = this.getReactively('items');
    const tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    }, {
        total: data.length,
        getData: (params) => {

        }
    });

    tableParams.reload(); // triggers the getData function
    return tableParams;
}


<table ng-table="ctrl.itemTableParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data track by $index">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.dateCreated}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I log the data in `getData`, it has items in it. But, like I said, it's not rendering in the table.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Your `items` method calls `this.myService.getItems()` but the service has a method `getInputs`, not `getItems`. Is this a typo just in the SO question or is it in your actual app too?

Comment: @noppa sorry, that was a typo in the question, not the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you just need to return the data in `getData`. The old docs were using `$defer.resolve` and was not returning the resolved data. The current version (1.0.0) isn't using it anymore.

```
this.helpers({
  items() {
    return this.myService.getItems();
  },
  itemTableParams() {
    const data = this.getReactively('items');

    return new NgTableParams({
      page: 1,
      count: 10
    }, {
      total: data.length,
      getData: (params) => {
        const filteredData = filterData(data); // do something

        return filteredData;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getData` method isn't being called because you fetch the `data` asynchronously but use it synchronously. So when the controller is loaded initially, `getData` is called with unresolved data.

To fix this, you'll need to create the `NgTableParams` in the success callback of the `data` object:

```
data.$promise.then((data) => {
 // create NgTableParams here
});
```

Comment: is this valid for `angular-meteor`? I tried doing that and `$promise` is undefined.